# Disable E_STRICT errors in php.ini file still throws the errors

Tags: php, ini, error-reporting

I'm trying to disable `E_STRICT` errors in my `php.ini` file but it still throws the error. I'm using `PHP 5.4.10` with a `MAMP` (not PRO version).

With `phpinfo` I've located the `php.ini` file in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini`

I've changed:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

Then i've restarted `Apache` but it still throw the error, where I'm wrong?

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted it.

Comment: PHP scripts can modify the value of `error_reporting` at runtime. Just because you set it in php.ini, doesn't mean the running script hasn't changed it to its liking.

Comment: Yes, in fact the problem was on a `CakePHP` configuration. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_STRICT`.

If you didn't have access to php.ini, you could put this in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value error_reporting 30711
```

This is the E_ALL value (32767) and the removing the E_STRICT (2048) and E_NOTICE (8) values.

If you don't have access to the .htaccess file or it's not enabled, you can put this at the top of the PHP section of any script

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT)
```