# ZF1: E_STRICT messages still appear after disabling

Tags: php, zend-framework

While migrating to a new host with PHP 5.4.x from old host with 5.3.x. I'm stumbling into a problem with E_STRICT.

I know that E_STRICT became part of E_ALL as of PHP 5.4, thus I have disabled it in `php.ini.`
But I still get an error in combination with Zend_Session, meaning the first page load is ok, I get the frontpage. If I refresh or go to another subpage I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Session_Exception' with message
'Zend_Session::start() -
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/application/models/someapi.php(
Line:4): Error #2048 Declaration of Someapi::getBeverageSizes() should
be compatible with
My_Service_Someapi::getBeverageSizes($storenumber, $ordertype)
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/application/models/someapi/Order
.php(Line:1039): Error #2 Creating default object from empty value
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/application/models/someapi/Order
.php(Line:1039): Error #2 Creating default object from empty value' in
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/library/Zend/Session.php:490
Stack trace: #0
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/library/Zend/Session/Namespace.
php(143): Zend_Session::start(true) #1
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/application/Bootstrap.php(213):
Zend_Session_Namespace->__construct('someapi') #2
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/library/Zend/Application/
Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initO in
/var/www/vhost/dev3_domain_com/httpdocs/library/Zend/Session.php on line 490
```

I know I could/should fix my code, but it's quite tedious. The "Someapi" class is extended from "My_Service_Someapi" which in turn is extended from "Zend_Rest_Client" - to handle the webservice from our backend system.

Could it be that Zend Framework sets it's own error reporting? I know from [other SO-posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014871/disable-e-strict-errors-in-php-ini-file-still-throws-the-errors) that CakePHP does that.

Comment: Have you checked your `application.ini`? Maybe you have set the `phpSettings.error_reporting` setting.

Comment: Not set in application.ini